# Why is my initWithNib method not called when the view controller is loaded?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiviewcontroller, nib

I have an class that inherits from UIViewController. There, I want to make some ivar initialization like this:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle { // Load the view nib
    NSLog(@"Hello Earth!");
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle]) {
        self.visibleIndex = 0;
        NSLog(@"Hello Planet!");
    }
    return self;
}
```

For some reason I do see the contents that were loaded from the nib. But for another reason this initializer will never be called. I never get the log messages. What's wrong with that? I have a nib for sure, so actually this would have to be called, right?

Answer (score 5):

This method isn't used if your UIViewController is being created by a nib. You need to override viewDidLoad:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Hello Planet");
}
```

initWithNibName is only used if you are actually instantiating the controller by code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are thinking of `viewLoaded`, not `initWithNibName`. viewLoaded is what's called if you want to setup a view programmatically. `initWithNibName` is called if you are loading with a nib.... hence the name? But the setting up of the view shouldn't be done until `viewDidLoad`, but other initialisation stuff should be done in `initWithNibName`, for instance, setting up any arrays or other variables.